# Зачем нужны "Человеко-понятные URL"?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, чпу

Я далек от веб-программирования, но на сайте периодически возникают вопросы, как сделать "Человеко-понятные URL".

Вопрос: А зачем вообще нужны "Человеко-понятные URL"? Разве кто-то смотрит в адресную строку после входа на сайт? Или разве кто-то набирает "Человеко-понятные URL" в адресной строке?

Comment: Для того, чтобы пользователю было проще запомнить ссылку. Хотя, имхо, проще запомнить `/news/04-11-2019`, чем `/news/segodnya-etot-den`.

Comment: Это по большей части для поисковой оптимизации **SEF URL** (search engines friendly url). Стоит еще отметить, что когда в адресной строке начинаешь набирать, браузер дает подсказку не только мета-заголовка ранее посещенной страницы, но и части URL страницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Человекопонятный URL (сокр. ЧПУ, также семантический URL, англ. friendly URL[⇨]) — URL-путь, состоящий из понятных слов, вместо идентификаторов, и отражающий файловую структуру сайта[⇨]. Например, вместо /c14/3/97/ или /index.php?cat=10&subcat=2&id=41 будет /product/phone/Samsung/.

Человекопонятные пути улучшают удобство использования. Кроме того, позволяют по названию ссылки заранее предполагать содержимое страницы по ней и представлять структуру сайта.

Технически URL может содержать только буквы латинского алфавита и некоторые символы. Все другие символы, включая русские буквы, кодируются (percent‐encoding) и могут выглядеть вроде %D0%9B%D1%83%D0%BA. Поэтому, обычно в адресах используют латиницу, чтобы избегать осложнений для пользователей. ([источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_URL))